# Decimals in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I am writing a Swift app and am dealing with decimals in a database (stored in mysql as decimals, with 2 digits. Basically it's sales someone made each day, so generally anything from $0 to $1000, but not millions, and nothing insane in terms of trailing decimals, just always rounded to 2 decimal places).

Referencing this helped me out:
[How to properly format currency on ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787759/how-to-properly-format-currency-on-ios)

..But I wanted to just do a quick sanity check here and make sure this strategy is ok.
i.e I would use NSDecimal or NSDecimalNumber (is there a preferred swift equivalent??)

What would you all recommend I do when dealing with currency in Swift? I'd like to use the locale-based currency symbol as well. I have a class called Sales that contains the amount in question. What do you recommend the datatype to be?

Apologies if I am coming off lazy, I actually have some ideas on what to do but feel a little overwhelmed at the "right" approach, especially in a locale-sensitive way, and wanted to check in here with you all.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update for Swift 3:** A [`Decimal` type](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/decimal) is now available with built-in support for operators like `*`, `/`, `+`, `<`, etc. When used in an Any context (passed to Objective-C), it's bridged to `NSDecimalNumber`.

---

Old answer:

`NSDecimal` is not really supported in Swift (it's a weird opaque pointer type), but [`NSDecimalNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdecimalnumber) is — and as in Obj-C, it's the best thing to use for base-ten arithmetic (because it actually does its operations in base ten). `NSLocale`, `NSNumberFormatter` and friends all work too and should satisfy your localization needs.

Comment: Thanks so much! So you would recommend my class properties to be NSDecimalNumber and not of type Decimal, correct? When I am converting a string that looks like "5000.52" to a NSDecimalNumber, are there any special rules to consider?

Comment: What do you mean by Decimal? I would recommend the [Number and Value Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/NumbersandValues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000038i) guide.

Comment: sorry I meant 'Double'!!

Comment: Of course it depends what you are doing, but you should [understand floating-point binary rounding error](http://floating-point-gui.de/formats/binary/) — and know that if your numbers are in base ten then NSDecimal(Number) does not have the same problems because it represents base-ten numbers natively.

Comment: To clarify, "5000.52" would be represented by NSDecimal as 500052×10^-2 but in a regular IEEE floating point number as 1.220830078×2^12.

Comment: thank you! So NSDecimalNumber and NSNumberFormat are the right way to do it

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3 now has a Decimal (value) type which is bridged to NSDecimalNumber.