# convert to currency using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a values like that: 100, 1220, 10015 basically last 2 digits are cents and I need to convert to dollar (currency) format similar to:
1.00, 12.20, 100.15

Can somebody suggest a quick implementation?

Comment: `your_number / 100`?

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = 1011
var b = Double(a) / 100
```

Comment: Doesn't work for anything like `100, 200` etc.  Will only have one decimal.

Comment: @chrisz Of course this will work with 100 and 200. It will work for any number converted from cents to dollars. It's all a matter of how you convert the `Double` to a `String.

Comment: You can then take the number shown above and convert it to a currency formatting string using the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11787799/3708242